# NestJS unitesting Middleware

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to unit test a middleware to avoid sending a request but I'm actually not able to retreive the middleware with `.get`

```
import { NestApplicationContext } from '@nestjs/core';
import { BodyParserMiddleware } from '../../../src/config/body-parser/body-parser.middleware';
import { FeaturesModule } from '../../../src/features/features.module';

describe('CatsController', () => {
  let app: NestApplicationContext;
  beforeAll(() => {
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  });

  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return an array of cats', async () => {
      console.log(app.get(BodyParserMiddleware));
    });
  });
});
```

my app module looks like this

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FeaturesModule } from './features/features.module';

@Module({
  imports: [FeaturesModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and the last one feature module

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BodyParserMiddleware } from '../config/body-parser/body-parser.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
  ],
})
export class FeaturesModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(BodyParserMiddleware).forRoutes('api/v*/*/get-many');
  }
}
```

`Nest could not find BodyParserMiddleware element (this provider does not exist in the current context)`

this is the error that im having

anyone knows how to retreive the middleware from the app container?

Also when I try to get the Features module to see if there is any clue there where I can go I receive

```
FeaturesModule {}
```

Comment: Try adding `{ strict: false }` to the `app.get()` as a second parameter. Also, where do you add `BodyParserMiddleware` to a `providers` array?

Comment: I'm not providing anyware as the documentation doesn's said so. At least for the middlewares

Comment: Still not working with the strict false :(

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't say you have to use `providers` for the class based middleware. However, if you don't add it to a `providers` then `app.get` will never work.

Comment: It's what I thought. Should I add it as a provider to the Features module?

Comment: I guess the main question is how are you trying to unit test the middleware? Why do you need to `get` it from the DI container?

Comment: The how you have it right over there in my question. And Why? Because I have a large monolith and testing that middleware with e2e test sending a request for each filter is expensive for me. So, unit test should take less that a full http request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251347/discussion-between-jay-mcdoniel-and-juli1234).